Вероятность выпадения значений на 20 гранных костях
Пожалуйста, помогите найти решение в виде формулы (необязательно excel).
Условие:

Бросаем 4 кости. Каждая имеет 20 граней.

Три из четырёх костей имеют по 3 успешных значения каждая.

Четвёртая кость имеет 5 успешных значений.


Вопрос:

Как будет выглядеть формула вероятности, где при броске 4-х костей выпадет:

1.1 Одно успешное значение
2.2 Два успешных значения
3.3 Три успешных значения
4.4 Четыре успешных значения

Возможно ли составить формулу, где можно менять количество успешных значений на костях? Планирую сделать формулу в excel со ссылкой на ячейки с редактируемыми успешными значениями.

Ps
уже задавал подобный вопрос, но некорректно его сформулировал, за что прошу прощения у всех откликнувшихся форумчан.

Только раз, только у нас... Вывод писать не буду, но результаты такие. Пусть p1 - вероятность для трех костей (в вашем случае 2/20), p2 - для четвертой кости (у вас 5/20). Тогда вероятности, что выпадет:
0:  (1-p1)^3 (1-p2)   
1:  p2(1-p1)^3+3(1-p2)p1(1-p1)^2   
2:  3p1^2(1-p1)(1-p2)+3p1p2(1-p1)^2
3:  3p2p1^2(1-p1)+p1^3(1-p2)  
4:  p1^3p2

Можете убедиться, что сумма дает 1 :)

Большое спасибо Вам за ответ! Правильно ли я Вас понял, под порядковым номером 0 — это одно успешное значение, 1 — два успешных значения, 2 — три, 3 — четыре. Так?

0 - это ноль успешных значений, что непонятно-то?...

Для не посвященных это волшебство какое-то. Всё не понятно. :)

Ещё раз спасибо Вам! Всех благ Вам!

@StanislavVolodarskiy Ну второй раз подробно всё расписывать — все ж таки увольте...
